# Python itertools slice stop position variable

Tags: python

Im using itertools to index through a csv file and the amount of rows will vary so I would like to replace the stop value with a variable and populate the value of the Variable from the user input, but i recieve: ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize

Is it possible and how?

below is what created my error

```
BDQTY = input('How many rows should I index? ')

Col = csv.reader(open(Root+ '/SNS/CartonsCarton')

for row in itertools.islice(Col, 0, BDQTY):
    tags = row
    for I in range(len(tags)):
        print(row[I])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `str` returned by `input` to an `int` first.

```
BDQTY = int(input(...))  # Ignoring the possibility of a ValueError
```

If you care about handling inputs that can't be converted to `int` values,

```
while True:
    x = input("How many ... ")
    try:
        BDQTY = int(x)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Im concatenating this same variable in another part of the code. if I change it to an in the that part of my code will error out. So I converted the input into another variable and it works